# PDF reader with thumbnail preview in the opening dialog

Tags: arch-linux, pdf, qt, okular

Situation: I download lots of PDFs which have unhelpful file names, such as arXiv papers (thanks, `1807.03042.pdf`). I'm often reading one of them in Okular and want to switch to another, say just to look up a reference, but the file open dialog lists only the names so it takes some effort to find the right file. I'd love to have a preview pane there or just the first page thumbnail for each file.

**Is there any PDF reader for Linux that has such a preview feature?** (I am on Arch if that changes things.)

I'm aware that various file managers do that, but I was hoping to avoid running another app given that I just want to open the PDFs.

I am happy to tinker with Okular's code as well (it uses Qt for the UI), but from my googling so far it doesn't seem like Qt has a magic "thumbnails on" switch, and would require actually writing the full previewer...

Comment: If I give okular a directory name as its argument, it opens what appears to be a combined file containing the first page of each compatible document in the folder, and you can view thumbnails of those pages in the panel on the left, and clicking on them opens the corresponding file. Does that meet your needs?

Comment: @frabjous Wow, that is a cool feature. It doesn't really help in my case though - I don't see a way to open the previewed page directly? So I still have to figure out the filename (which is not printed in the preview), then close the preview, and rerun okular on the right file. I'm still hoping there might be a smoother way to do this.